# Como criar um Array dentro do outro

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Preciso criar um array que tenha indice e valores
`page_links` recebe os links de uma pagina

```
all_links_main = []
for link in page_links:
 all_links_main.append(link.get('href'))

produto = []

for link1 in all_links_main:
 page_one = requests.get(link1)
 print(page_one)
 soup_one = BeautifulSoup(page_one.content, 'html.parser')
```

preciso incluir em produto algo como:
indice 
`0` [nome, valor, imagem]
`1` [nome, valor, imagem]
...

Porém não estou conseguindo.

Ao meu entender seria um array dentro do outro (bidimensional), sou novo em python.

Comment: Você precisa dentro de uma posição de array ter os valores de nome, valor e imagem? Desculpe, não entendi bem.

Comment: Preciso fazer isso mesmo.

Comment: Não seria melhor então criar uma classe que possui esses atributos e então adicionar a classe ao array?

Comment: Eu preciso pegar os produtos de um site, exemplo site a
E salvar o nome, valor e imagem desse produto no array para depois salvar no banco.
não sei como poderia fazer dessa forma que citou.

Comment: Verifica esse exemplo com classe, https://pastebin.com/eJLvBQ4J

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97878/discussion-between-jb-and-daniel-mendes).

Comment: @DanielMendes havia dito que não iria utilizar com classe, mais usei tive alguns problemas ao implementar com classe para salvar no banco os arrays com o `executemany` apresentou um erro: `TypeError: 'Produto' object is not iterable` sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Para colocar uma lista dentro de outra lista, basta usar o método `append` na lista externa com a lista interna como parâmetro.

```
a = []
for _ in range(10):
     a.append([1, 2, 3]) # Lista a agora contém 10 sub-listas [1, 2, 3]
```

Você também pode usar `list comprehension` para deixar o código mais compacto

```
a = [[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(10)] # Equivalente ao código anterior
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui, acredito que seria isso mesmo.